# Is it possible to make one flex line stretch without stretching the other one?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to implement a responsive sidebar, that changes to a fixed height header when there is not enough horizontal space.

The following code works, except that I'm unable to make the second flex line stretch and occupy maximum space, while giving the first line the minimum space needed.

As per the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-lines):

> In a multi-line flex container (even one with only a single line), the cross size of each line is the minimum size necessary to contain the flex items on the line (after alignment due to align-self), and the lines are aligned within the flex container with the align-content property.

But I seem to be missing something, because the available vertical seem to be equally shared by the flex lines.

I tried giving `.bar` `min-hieght: 5em`, but it is still occupying half of the height when wrapping occurs.

Is it impossible to implement without using media queries?

---

Code:

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  color: white;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bar {
  background: grey;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;

  min-width: 15em;
  min-height: 5em;

  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
  background: darkgrey;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;

  flex-grow: 999;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 40em;
}
```

```html
<aside class="bar">
  <h1>Bar</h1>
</aside>
<main class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
</main>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/074r8nhs/31/

Comment: Make `.bar` to have `flex-grow: 0`

Comment: to control this you have to switch to column direction thus using media query

Comment: @YongQuan, it only affects the growth in main axis. It still doesn't reduce the height when wrapping.